# Passing data to d3 after preprocessing in a Flask app

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, flask

I have a simple Flask app that is used to query a database based on input from an html form, then cleans and transforms the data into a json object to be feed into a d3 visualization. I'm having trouble figuring out how to feed my json object into my d3 code.

Here is the basic Flask app:

Import things to note about the code vertica_query, parse_to_json, and clean_dataframe are all functions I wrote for processing the data. The clean_dataframe function is necessary to clean the data and ready for transformation to json, but it also enables the data to be displayed under the d3 visualization as an html table, thats why I don't just have one larger function that queries, clean, and transforms to json.

```
import os
import json
from flask import (Flask, Response, request, 
                   render_template, redirect, 
                   url_for, make_response,
                   jsonify)

from query_clean import vertica_query, parse_to_json, clean_dataframe

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/build-chart", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def build_chart():
    id = request.form['id']
    table = clean_dataframe(vertica_query(id))
    chart_json = parse_to_json(table)

    return render_template('render.html', data=table, chart_json=chart_json)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

**What I've tried so far**

Pass out the chart_json to my build_chart view like so:

```
<script> var chartData = {{ chart_json | tojson | safe }}; </script>
```

and then attempting to read into d3 like so but it doesn't read into d3 properly I get error being thrown from my d3.min.js and my chart.js (the d3 that builds the chart)

```
d3.json(chartData, function(error, graph) {

    var nodeMap = {};
    graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
    graph.links = graph.links.map(function(x) {
      return {
        source: nodeMap[x.source],
        target: nodeMap[x.target],
        value: x.value,
        color: x.color
      };
    });
```

I also tried creating a view that returns the json object and then link that view directly d3.json("") somethign like this:

```
@app.route("/stream", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def stream():
    id = request.form['id']
    table = clean_dataframe(vertica_query(id))
    chart_json = parse_to_json(table)

    return jsonify(chart_json) 

d3.json("http://localhost:5000/stream", function(error, graph) {

    var nodeMap = {};
    graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
    graph.links = graph.links.map(function(x) {
      return {
        source: nodeMap[x.source],
        target: nodeMap[x.target],
        value: x.value,
        color: x.color
      };
    });
```

that works, but the problem with that arises because I don't know how to grab id with this view since the action= parameter in the html form is set to the build_chart view

```
<form action="/build_chart" method="POST"></form>
```

additionally I would be querying the database twice, which is not ideal.

Ideally I would be able to query the database create my table and chart_json variable once and then pass them around to the views that need the data. Is there any way to accomplish that with Flask?

Answer (score 0):

`d3.json` actually fires off an ajax request, so in your case you don't really need it if the data for the chart is actually rendered in the template as you showed. If you want to do it that way (I would recommend actually making an API call as you did in the second example...), just use the variable holding the data in your charting function:

```
<script>
  var chartData = {{ chart_json | tojson | safe }}; 
  makeSomeChart(chartData)
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah I would totally prefer the API way but how do I get the id entered in the HTML form for the stream view when the action is set to the build_chart view?

Comment: make it a parameter in the stream API route, and use jquery to get the value of the input

Comment: I don't know if that solves the problem because my form action is set to navigate to the /build-chart view so the problem is I cannot access the id input from the html from because the form only communicates with /build-chart and not /stream